# Upload Online File to Firebase Storage Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I get an audiofile from an API call, and I want to upload this file to my Firebase storage. The API calls returns:

> {"success": true, "path": "https://developer.wontgivetheexactpath.mp3"}

When I click on the path, it automatically downloads the audio in my computer, but I don't want that. I want it to go directly in my Storage. I tried this:

```
 var audioFile = createAudio(
    text: 'What is love? I don\'t know, but it doesn\'t matter.');
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("audio/$audioFile");
ref.putFile(File(audioFile.toString()));
```

Note that `createAudio()` is the function that returns the path resulting from the API call.

Answer (score 0):

It really won't forward it this way, for flutter it may vary according to the OS, you will need to use the packge [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path) to standardize the OS paths, save in a temporary path and with this temporary path you will be able to change the folder and do the navigation you want, yes I know it's annoying but it's a solution that I already implemented years ago and it worked

Comment: Could you be more precise on how to do so? I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. I had to use the package `dio` to download the file on my computer first, then delete it. here is the code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> downloadFile(String url, String fileName) async {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName.mp3';
  await dio.download(url, filePath);
  return File(filePath);
}
```

Then I upload to Firebase Storage and delete it:

```
     Future<void> uploadAudioToFirebase() async {
      final audioPath = await createAudio(text: 'What is love? I don\'t know, but it doesn\'t matter.');
    
      if (audioPath['success']) {
        final String url = audioPath['path'];
        final fileName = url.split('/').last;  // Extract the file name from the URL
        final localFile = await downloadFile(url, fileName);
    
        final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("audio/$fileName");
        await ref.putFile(localFile);

    // Optionally, delete the local file after upload
        await localFile.delete();
  } else {
    print('Failed to get audio path from API.');
  }
}
```